# How to change a computer's domain in C #

Tags: c#, powershell, dns

I need to make a system for domain change and it is necessary to execute this code via C #, but I have tried everything and I cannot.
To run the script in PowerShell, you must initialize it as an administrator. In PowerShell, it works without problems.

Code in Power Shell:

```
$domain = "NameDomain"`enter code here`
$password = "pwd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "$domain\User" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -Restart -Force
```

Code in C#;

```
var scriptfile = @"$domain = ""dominio""; $password = ""psw"" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force; $username = ""domain\user""; $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password); Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -Restart -Force";
```

Method used:

```
    private string RunScript(string script)
    {

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pip = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pip.Commands.AddScript(script);
        pip.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        Collection<PSObject> results = pip.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Are you running your .NET process as administrator?

Comment: You are not really doing it in C# so the "necessary to execute this code via C#" is kind of not true, as your C# code just calls Powershell\. Really doing it in C# would mean using the appropriate libraries that allows to manage system settings (if it exists).